# Get teams channels where login user has access using graph api

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams

I want to retrieve all the teams channel where login user has access, what is the best possible way to achieve that?

For example : There are 5 teams where all users has access but in team 1 there are 5 channel and user 1 has access to 3 of them. Now how do i return all this 3 channel in a single api call ?

Comment: I presume you're referring to Microsoft Teams, but you may want to clarify.

Comment: Please take a look at [List channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using graph API